# How to properly apt-pinn (by defaulting packages to our main release)

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I noticed couple of days ago that all these years I've been using apt very, very wrong. My intentions have been sticking to the release I'm using, that is debian testing, so if new package got installed, it'd be pulled from the **testing** repo by default. If package had to be installed from stable or unstable, it needed to be installed explicitly via

```
apt-get install package/<stable|unstable>
```

Turns out I didn't, still don't, quite get the package pinning idea. From the documentation I understand pinning simply controls where the updates for packages get pulled from; eg if there's larger ver of some package available in unstable, whether it should be pulled or not. In reality, if new package is installed and **unstable** contains the newest version for it, it gets pulled from there. This is obviously not what I want.

How should apt be configured, so all the packages would still be pulled from our release's repo by default?

Contents of my configs:

### /etc/apt/apt.conf:

```
APT::Default-Release "testing";
```

### /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# stable:
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stable main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stable main non-free contrib

# unstable:
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ unstable main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ unstable main non-free contrib

# testing
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib

# testing/updates
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-backports, previously on backports.debian.org
# do NOT use backports if on testing; testing doesnt have those:
#deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free

# archive (for old fonts for instance):
#deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian woody main

# 3rd party:
....
```

### /etc/apt/preferences:

```
Package: *
Pin: release l=Debian-Security
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 995

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 650

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50

Package: *
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 1
```

Comment: Your configuration seems OK to me; could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt-cache policy miller`?

Comment: Ugh... did apt-get install --dry-run for wine, and it **did** pull it from testing. Could some packages be pulled from unstable, because some of the dependencies are from there?

Comment: Sorry, `wine` was a silly example since its versions in testing and unstable are the same. Could you try again with `miller`? Or give specific examples of packages which you'd expect from testing but come from unstable?